# Change iTerm2 profile depending on current directory

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm

Using my .bash_profile, I used to change my iTerm2 profile per machine with the following command:

```
echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=ssh\a"
```

Now, I want to change it depending on my current working directory.

Ideally must work something like this:

- Once I enter /mnt/production or any subfolder inside, iTerm should change to production profile.
- Once I leave that directory, should change to bash profile.

Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution using [bash-preexec](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec).

That utility have the following function:

`precmd` Executed just before each prompt. Equivalent to PROMPT_COMMAND, but more flexible and resilient.

To install bash-preexec:

```
brew install bash-preexec
```

Then I have to add the following to my .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/bash-preexec.sh ]; then
    . $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/bash-preexec.sh
    precmd() {
        if [[ $PWD == /mi/prod/path/produccion* ]]; then
            if [ -z $shouldChangeProfile ]; then
                echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=production\a"
            fi
            shouldChangeProfile=1
        elif [ "$shouldChangeProfile" == "1" ]; then
            echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=bash\a"
            unset shouldChangeProfile
        fi
    }
fi
```

Inside the `precmd` function is where I change the profile according to my needs.

`shouldChangeProfile` prevents unnecessary profile changes.